# How to get a substring from the specific string in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have

```
string filepath = @"F:\first_folder\Node3_V_1.3";
```

I have a button named `version_check`

On the click of this button i want to print the message:

> upgrading node3 to version 1.3

The details are fetched from string `filepath`. How do I code this in C#.

Comment: First thing you probably want is to use `Path.GetFileName`. Then you might want to consider a regular expression...

Answer (score 2):

You can do in this way

```
version_check.Click += version_check_Click;  //subscription of the event

public void version_check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = @"F:\first_folder\Node3_V_1.3";
    var name = Path.GetFileName(filepath).Split(new[] {'_', 'V'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (name.Length < 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to update");
        return;
    }    
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Upgrading {0} to version {1} ...", name[0], name[1]));
}
```

Debug Information:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple using the already available classes in the NET Framework,

The [Path class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path(v=vs.110).aspx) has a method `GetFileName` that takes the last part of a pathname also if it is not a real filename but just a folder....

```
string filePath =  @"F:\first_folder\Node3_V_1.3";
string lastFolder = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
Console.WriteLine(lastFolder);
```

Now, if your `lastFolder` is regularly composed of three parts (IE, software, V per version and finally the version number, you could use the Split method of the [String class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)  to divide you `lastFolder` in three parts

```
string[] parts = lastFolder.Split('_');
Console.WriteLine("Upgrading {0} to version {1}", parts[0], parts[2]);
```

If you work with C# 6.0 you could also write the last statement using [string interpolation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx) with

```
Console.WriteLine($"Upgrading {parts[0]} to version {parts[2]}");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the sample folder path you gave,

```
 private void version_check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string version =   "F:\\first_folder\\Node3_V_1.3";
           var result = version.Substring(version.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
           string[] splitString = result.Split('_').ToArray();
           MessageBox.Show("upgrading "+ splitString[0] + " to version" + splitString[2]);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex solution:

```
string filepath = @"F:\first_folder\Node3_V_1.3";
string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
Match m = Regex.Match(filename, "^(?<name>.+)_V_(?<version>.+)$");
string output = string.Format("upgrading {0} to version {1}",
                              m.Groups["name"].Value,
                              m.Groups["version"].Value);
```

String.Split solution:

```
string filepath = @"F:\first_folder\Node3_V_1.3";
string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
string[] parts = filename.Split(new[] { "_V_" }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
string output = string.Format("upgrading {0} to version {1}",
                              parts[0],
                              parts[1]);
```